# Saving symbology of all layers in mxd to enable quick reverting back to certain "look"?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.2, layers, symbology

I am using ArcMap 10.2 and would like to set multiple variations of the layers symbologies.  In autocad this would be the equivalent of setting the layer state.

Comment: There are many options here... the easiest would be to save separate MXD's. Alternatively, you could group all your layers and save as a layer file and then just turn off and on (or add and remove) the layer files for each representation... if your used to using cad maybe legends don't matter....or don't need to be dynamic.

Comment: Have you tried saving it as .lyr file? How does that not satisfy your requirement?

Answer (score 1):

There are several approaches to realize this as Mike already posted. Making a copy of the MXD or the layer files is a very good and pragmatic approach. Depending on the number of different symbologies it could get confusing very fast.

Alternativly there exists the ESRI technology of **representations** to store different symbologies. The symbology here is stored inside the data and not in the MXD or the layer file in contrast. Please note, that the representation technology is very sophisticated and originaly was introduced to provide complexly symbology for catographic purposes. Please have a look at the [representation tutorial](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/pdf/cartographic-representations-tutorial.pdf) if you are not afraid of the complexity.